# How to reinitialize text widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to return the search result of the user in the GUI itself.
This is the following code which I am using

```
def printResult(searchResult):
global resultsFrame
text = Text(resultsFrame)

for i in searchResult:
    text.insert(END,i+'\n')
text.pack(side=TOP)
```

where searchResult is a list which has all the statements to be printed on the screen and this is how I declared resultsFrame in the code (before root.mainloop())
I am using global so that it makes changes to the existing frame but it rather adds another frame below it.
How to make changes in the already existing text widget?

```
resultsFrame = Frame(root)
resultsFrame.pack(side=TOP)
```

For reference here is an image of the GUI:

[image: Creation of new Text widget]

EDIT : 
***Issue Solved***

I declared the frame outside the function

```
resultsFrame = Frame(root)
resultsFrame.pack(side=TOP)
text = Text(resultsFrame)

def printResult(searchResult):
   global resultsFrame
   global text
   text.delete("1.0",END)
   for i in searchResult:
       text.insert(END,str(i)+'\n')
   text.pack(side=TOP)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The methods for inserting and deleting text are all well documented.

Comment: I did try deleting but the issue is the function gets called each time I press the submit button and it ends up adding one more Text Widget to the frame./
I did use .delete("1.0",END) as well

Comment: Remove the code that creates a new text widget each time. Just create it once when your program starts up.

Comment: why dont you define the `resultFrame` outside the function? that will solve the problem.

Comment: "How to make changes in the already existing text widget?" the first time your function is called there is no "already existing text widget" and every other time you have no reference to the text widget you create inside the `printResults` function.  Does that maybe shed a light on why it is working the way it is?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
global resultsFrame
text = Text(resultsFrame)

def printResult(searchResult):
    for i in searchResult:
        text.insert(END,i+'\n')
...
text.pack(side=TOP)
```

This should solve your issue.